# Mono touch Dialog RTL overlap issue for Entry Element in Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

When EntryElement is used for Arabic language the UITextfield overlap with the Title Label

```
EntryElement entryElementSerialNo = new BasicEntryElement("Serial No.", "Enter Sr no", number) { TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Right, KeyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad};

var section= new Section("Test") { entryElementSerialNo };

this.Root = new RootElement("Test"){ section };
```

What should be the way to display the entryfield to push it to left side to overcome the overlap issue.

Comment: MTD has not been updated in 5 years and I would avoid using it

Comment: [Apple's official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiappearance) introduces: iOS applies appearance changes when a view enters a window, but it doesn't change the appearance of a view that's already in a window. To change the appearance of a view that's currently in a window , remove the view from the view hierarchy and then put it back.